# Maximum call stack exceeded error On function Find Small Common Multiple

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a function to find the smallest common multiple by numbers in range. For example if i pass smallestCommons([1,3]),  find the smallest common multiple of both 1 and 3 that is also evenly divisible by all numbers between 1 and 3. The answer here would be 6.

I use the recursion to find the Smallest Common Multiple, but if i pass the second index of array with number more than 12 than it will output maximum call stack exceeded

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  arr.sort((a,b) => b - a);
  let newArr = [];

  for(let i = arr[0]; i >= arr[1]; i--) {
    newArr.push(i);
  }
  
  function findCommon(multiples) {
    let currentValue = newArr[0] * multiples;
    if(newArr.every(item => currentValue % item == 0)) {
      return currentValue;
    } else {
      return findCommon(multiples + 1);
    }
  }

 return findCommon(1);
}

console.log(smallestCommons([1,13]));
```

Comment: @trincot sorry i am new to javascript , so can i know what should i change to make it a good loop?

Comment: Why don't you look up Least Common Multiple (LCM)? The algorithm has been published so many times.

Comment: @trincot Please clarify why it's not a good loop, and how it could be improved. @Ryan k Welsome to Stack Overflow. I see you `console.log()` at the end there. Could you provide the current output and any errors in the console?

Comment: @trincot because i am doing freecodecamp javascript intermediate algorithm , so i am trying to do algorithm my self without copying other people algorithm.

Comment: @AxelKöhler the current output just show that the maximum call stack exceeded, but if i write console.log(smallestCommons[1,12]), it works. But then if i use numbers more than 12 it will show maximum call stack exceeded

Comment: I think your problem could have been resolved with a simple web search. The `maximum call stack exceeded` error appears because you are using a recursive function that is called too many times (12 levels deep in this case), causing a memory limit overflow. Try to solve the problem using another method (with a loop for instance).

Comment: What is the expected output for [1,13]? And why?

Comment: @AxelKöhler okay, i will try to think of another method using for loop.

Comment: no, that is not the problem guys. Give me one minute^^

Comment: What would be the expected output for [1, 4, 16, 24]? Please provide examples of input and expected output.

Comment: @trincot the expected output for [1,13] is 360360 , for this function i am actually looking for the smallest common multiple of both 1 and 13 that is also divisible by all numbers between 1 and 13, i am so sorry that i didn't explain the purpose of my function because this is the first time i try to ask a question in stack overflow.

Comment: Yo should look up operator predence.
And this part of the loop
if(newArr.every(item => currentValue % item == 0)) {
              return currentValue;
          } else {
            return findCommon(multiples + 1);
          }

Your maximum call Stack exceeded, since you wrote it recursively. You never match the if() condition, you always get to the else part. Play it through in your head, after having checked the operator predence. Or better write it down on a piece of paper, you'll see.

Comment: *"also divisible by all numbers between 1 and 13"*: oh, I see. That information is not in your question. Can you update it? Does it mean your input will always be an array with exactly two values? If so, why doesn't your function just take two arguments?

Comment: Alex is right, you should write this not recursively to prevent that. Or find a recursive way with less calls

Comment: @trincot no, my input will be the numbers that is the smallest common multiple between min and max numbers , so , for example i write console.log([1,3] . The output would be 6 because it is the smallest common multiple between 1 and 3 and it can be evenly divided by 2 which is the number between 1 and 3

Comment: @Leviathan thanks , i will try to find another method without using recursive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive algorithm is going to have to check a whole lot of coefficients, and so it is no surprise you bump into a stack overflow error.

For finding the least common multiple of a list of numbers, you can use the rule that you can replace any pair in that list with their least common multiple and continue from there. This way you reduce the list step by step until you have one value left.

And actually, it is not needed to really *create* that list. You can just iterate the values from minimum to maximum and accumulate the least common multiple according to the above principle:

```js
// Euclid's algorithm
function gcd(a, b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

function lcm(a, b) {
    return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}

// lcm of all numbers in the range [a, b]:
function lcmOfRange(a, b) {
    let result = a;
    for (let i = a + 1; i <= b; i++) {
        result = lcm(result, i);
    }
    return result;
}

// lcm of all numbers in the range [min(arr), max(arr)]
function lcmOfMinMax(arr) {
    return lcmOfRange(Math.min(...arr), Math.max(...arr));
}

console.log(lcmOfMinMax([1, 3])); // 6
console.log(lcmOfMinMax([1, 13])); // 360360
```

Comment: thanks @tricot , your code works, but i wonder if we are trying to solve an algorithm like this , should we look for other people algorithm or try to solve it ourselves?

Comment: I think it is quite fine to look into the subject first, because finding Euler's algorithm by yourself without knowing it, would be quite unusual and make you a great mathematician. We should build on the shoulders of the heroes of the past.